# Set Min and Max Value for Int? Android

Tags: android, int, max, min

Is there a way to set minimum and maximum value of an integer? I did some research but I couldn't find anything useful. I need to set min value 0 and max value 30, so when user is touching button(TouchListener) numbers will go from 30 to 0. I know it can be done with if else statements but I am looking for a better way.

```
     int total= Integer.MAX_VALUE + 30;
     int left= Integer.MIN_VALUE + 0;

        total= 30;
        left = 30;
            .....
    onTouchListener...
    switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

    left--;
    setText();
break;
    ...
protected void setText() {
    count.setText(left + "/" + total);
}
```

But the problem is, int value goes under 0. -1 -2 etc etc
How can I stop this? How to set Min int value?

Comment: Dont call  setText(); if left < 0.

Comment: It won't set text but the value will go under 0, besides  It could've been done like `if(left>0){left--;}` but I didn't want to use if else statements. aga's code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `left--;` with the following:

```
left -= (left > 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: This works :o Never thought of that. Thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Try to check left value before decrees by 1 :

```
if(left < 0){
   left--;
   setText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range seek bar which allow you to seek between two specific integer values.

Here is the link - https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/